# iPhone Objective C - Saving Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, save

I have a **NSMutableArray** of some instances of a custom class (it has a NSString, CGPoint, and a UILabel).

I need to **save** this array. I tried using **writeToFile:Atomically:** but that doesn't work with custom classes (I think). Is there any other **simple** way to save that? And how would i load it?

Thanks everybody in advance:) Any ideas, suggestions, pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`NSCoding`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to help with this, but I think you'll find it tricky to deal with the semantics of saving and restoring `UILabel`s. Would it not be possible just to store them in a nib file?

Comment: `UILabel` conforms to `NSCoding`, so it should be fine (as long as it's not a custom sublcass).

Comment: Yes, but he'll have to make sure it gets properly connected back up to its superviews when it's loaded back in. Certainly possible, but I'm not sure what application would call for it (except where a nib-file would do it better).